# MariaDB Can't init tc log

Tags: mariadb, centos

I've tried every solution on the Internet but my MariaDb server continue to fail, continue to betray me, continue to destroy my tiny DevOps world. My attempts to smooth the situation included all sorts of satisfaction: changing permissions, configs, removing log files, upgrading / reinstalling, moving her internal files up and around, removing other DBMS, removing everything except her but.... she has never been resisting so much for so long. My last and only hope for you guys to light the way through such critical moment in our relationships.

I'm using vagrant and the problem is in `datadir` option - when I use default path everything is ok but when I change it to vagrant shared folder Maria does not even start. I have copied all the /var/lib/mysql files to new folder.

I have Windows host, Centos guest and my configurations are:

**MariaDb version:**

```
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.17-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1
```

**Vagrantfile:**

```
# -*- mode: ruby; -*-

ENV['VAGRANT_DEFAULT_PROVIDER'] = 'virtualbox'

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box_url = "https://github.com/tommy-muehle/puppet-vagrant-boxes/releases/download/1.1.0/centos-7.0-x86_64.box"
  config.vm.box = "centos7"

  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "10.0.1.10"

  config.vm.synced_folder "mysql", "/vagrant/mysql", owner: "mysql", group: "mysql"

  config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "4096"]
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--cpus", "4"]
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--hwvirtex", "on"]
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--audio", "none"]
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--nictype1", "virtio"]
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--nictype2", "virtio"]
  end
end
```

**/etc/my.cnf.d/server.cnf:**

```
[mysqld]
user=mysql
datadir=/vagrant/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
symbolic-links=0
default-storage-engine=innodb

tmpdir = /tmp

character-set-server = utf8
init-connect="SET NAMES utf8"

expire_logs_days=2
skip-external-locking

key_buffer_size = 32M
max_allowed_packet = 32M
table_open_cache = 8192
table_definition_cache = 8192
sort_buffer_size = 16M
net_buffer_length = 16K
read_buffer_size = 8M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 8M
thread_cache_size = 128
thread_concurrency = 16

query_cache_size = 1024M
query_cache_limit = 2M
join_buffer_size = 32M

max_connections = 1024
max_connect_errors = 1024

connect_timeout=5

innodb_file_per_table
innodb_buffer_pool_size=2048M
innodb_read_io_threads=8
innodb_write_io_threads=8
innodb_lock_wait_timeout=5
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2
innodb_flush_method=O_DSYNC
innodb_log_file_size=64M
innodb_log_buffer_size=32M
innodb_log_files_in_group=2
innodb_thread_concurrency=16
innodb_open_files = 1000
innodb_sync_spin_loops=100

skip-name-resolve

log-error=/var/log/mariadb/mysqld.log
```

**MariaDb error log:**

```
2016-09-30 22:32:46 139758293125248 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2016-09-30 22:32:46 139758293125248 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2016-09-30 22:32:46 139758293125248 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2016-09-30 22:32:46 139758293125248 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2016-09-30 22:32:46 139758293125248 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.7
2016-09-30 22:32:46 139758293125248 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2016-09-30 22:32:46 139758293125248 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE crc32 instructions
2016-09-30 22:32:46 139758293125248 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 2.0G
2016-09-30 22:32:46 139758293125248 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2016-09-30 22:32:46 139758293125248 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2016-09-30 22:32:46 139758293125248 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2016-09-30 22:32:46 139758293125248 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2016-09-30 22:32:46 139758293125248 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.31-77.0 started; log sequence number 1600799
2016-09-30 22:32:46 139754263774976 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started
2016-09-30 22:32:46 139758293125248 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2016-09-30 22:32:46 139758293125248 [ERROR] Can't init tc log
2016-09-30 22:32:46 139758293125248 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Comment: Do you have enough space on partition with the log? Can you delete log file and restart?

Comment: @Stoleg Hi Stoleg, thank you for reply. There's a lot of free space on partition. I tried deleting the file, restarting and MariaDb creates it and does not start

Comment: Does account used by Maria, has `READ` permissions to destination folder? There may be a chance that it can create file with Write, but have no Read permission. Try doing same operations as Maria would do under its account. May be it cannot keep file open and locked?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Woohoo, I found it! For now, at least. Digging through the source suggests that this might have something to do with `mmap()` calls, and lo and behold - [VirtualBox has a bug in that area](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/819). Fortunately that same source hints at a workaround - the [log_bin option](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/the-mariadb-library/replication-and-binary-log-server-system-variables/#log_bin). Enable this (either from the command line as `--log_bin` or from the config file as `log_bin=ON`) and things start to work again!

#### Update

They're saying they've fixed it in VirtualBox 6.0.6!

Comment: Thank-you so much! This fixed my `tc.log` error using Virtualbox on a windows 10 host.

Comment: This seems to have been a significant bit of progress for me also, Windows 10 Home, Docker Toolbox 18.03.

Answer (score 48):

I ended up deleting the tc.log file in /var/lib/mysql. When I started mysql again, it created a new tc.log and started up.

```
sudo rm -f /var/lib/mysql/tc.log
```

Comment: while this feels somewhat unsafe it worked in my case!

Comment: It worked, but it's safer to use: `sudo mv /var/lib/mysql/tc.log /var/lib/mysql/tc_bkp.log`

Comment: In my case the tc.log was empty (0 bytes) and removing it did the trick. I assume the removal in this case is safe.

Comment: Thanks. created a backup copy of tc.log file and delete the original tc.log file worked for me.

Answer (score 9):

You can remove the `tc.log` in the data directory and remove old entries from mysql-bin.index (it is a text file, along with a list of binary logs). If this is a development box, you can remove the index file (mysql-bin.index) to force its recreation.

Also it could be related to the user ids between `mysql` user and the shared folder id owner, [here](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/99#issuecomment-145665645) is a snippet to do so.

Comment: Curious about the *cause* of this issue though, how can I avoid? Thanks

Comment: @3zzy - Read my answer.

Comment: @3zzy I didn't reproduce the bug yet.

Comment: This is a strange issue to encounter indeed. What exactly is stored in this file? I was in such haste to fix the problem I forgot to look at the one that was there. I may be able to provide more detail.

Comment: I suspect that an "out of disk space" error corrupted my tc.log today.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to get mysql/mariadb running again and **don't mind losing your data** (in a dev environment), this is what I did

Delete:
ib_logfile1
ib_logfile0
aria_log_control
aria_log.00000001
tc.log
ib_data1

start the server

Delete the schema (if it contains files, cd into the schema's folder, delete everything)

I then reimported the database from an old dump I had.

I then started mariadb, and it comes up fine.  The deleted files got recreated.
** Again this is for dev only. You could probably install your db**

Answer (score 1):

I also solved this error by removing the tc.log. With XAMPP the tc.log file is in the `XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql` folder - on my mac its located at: 
`/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/tc.log`

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue within MariaDB's official docker container. Removing the log file as the other answers offered did not help me. However, my issue was related to `mmap` as the accepted answer suggests.

[I found various solutions](https://serverfault.com/a/985541/408659) to correct this for my scenario.

1. [Activate Binary Log](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/activating-the-binary-log/)
2. Remove the conflict inhibiting mmap from functioning properly

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue when I tried to copy the database data folder.
So I changed to the data folder and executed following command to delete all log files:

```
rm -rf *log*
```

Then  I rebuilded the docker and issue was sorted.

Answer (score 0):

After I installed MySQL Workbench beside MariaDB 10.x on Ubuntu 19.10.x and suddenly MariaDB was disrupted `sudo mv /var/lib/mysql/tc.log /var/lib/mysql/tc_bkp.log` worked for me.